# How to override a lambda variable from a subclass in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, lambda, redis, symbols, monkeypatching

I am using the [Redis gem](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb) to access redis, and I would like .hgetall to symbolize the keys of the hashes it returns.  In [this thread](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb/issues/201), @pletern indicates a method of monkey patching the gem's _hashify method.

However this was a while ago, and the current implementation uses a lambda to `Hashify` the list returned from Redis, instead of a method. [See line 2728](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb/blob/master/lib/redis.rb#L2728)

I have been attempting to 'override' this lambda with my own implementation, following something similar what would be used for a method:

```
class MyRedis < Redis

  private

  Hashify =
    lambda { |array|
      hash = Hash.new
      array.each_slice(2) do |field, value|
        hash[field.to_sym] = value
      end
      hash
    }
end
```

and in my RedisService:

```
class RedisService
  class << self

    def hgetall(key)
      redis.hgetall("room:"+room_name)
    end

    private

    def redis
      @@redis ||= MyRedis.new
    end

  end
end
```

I have played around with my class and not been able to override the Hashify lambda in the gem.

Comment: Have you tried implementing it using the given hook in the post you linked to? (e.g. defining the `_hashify` method in your sub class? Your current issue, trying to redefine the `Hashify` constant has to do with your in ability to control instantiation. For example if any part of the code base calls `Redis.new` it has not escaped your subclass and will return to the parent class implementation of `Hashify`

Comment: I only ever call MyRedis.new, and yes I just tried defining _hashify and no luck

Comment: it doesn't matter so much what you call. You are inheriting all the methods from `Redis` so lets say for example you call `MyRedis::current` this will return a `Redis` instance not a `MyRedis` instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting your own `Hashify` in your subclass doesn't help, because the Ruby interpreter will use the constant defined in `Redis`, as the methods that call `Hashify.call` are defined there, too.

You can override `Redis::Hashify`, though. This will result in your lambda being used for all Redis connections and in `warning: already initialized constant Redis::Hashify`

```
require 'redis'

Redis::Hashify = lambda do |array|
  Hash.new.tap do |hash|
    array.each_slice(2) do |field, value|
      hash[field.to_sym] = value
    end
  end
end
```

Please note writing code that produces warnings is considered bad style by many developers. It might be better to modify the response of `Redis#hgetall` after you received it. If you don't mind using ActiveSupport, you can use it's `Hash#symbolize_keys`, for instance.

Comment: Is the performance lost of reiterating the keys to make them symbols so negligible that I shouldn't even consider that in my decision?

Comment: @AlexTurner It depends on the size of the responses you expect. Re-generating the keys _is_ an expensive operation, but unless you have really large response sets, it should be fast enough.

What you could also do is open a pull request to redis.rb so that it doesn't use a constant, but a class attribute.